# Opening a file over ssh in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am on Mac (Lion), using GNU/Emacs version 24.1. I have created a VM, and assigned it a static IP. 
I want to open/edit files using emacs. AFAI figured out, above version 23, the `tramp-mode` comes pre-installed. So i tried the following `C-x C-f /ssh:username@192.168.1.23:/path_to_file.rb` but what it does is creates a file with name **ssh:...rb.**

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Does it work if you start emacs with `emacs -q`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs 24 comes enabled with tramp-mode. In case you have put anything in your ~/.emacs.d directory or some init.el files to customize tramp mode, please remove them.

All you need to do is `C-x C-f ~//username@ip_address.` 
You will be asked for a password, provide it and enjoy!

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I have to SSH over and intermediate server? My university uses a system where we SSH into a serverpool, authenticate there, and then SSH -X from that session into one of the available clients there.

Comment: thanks, I did not know that tramp is enabled by default. Thats very helpful! In my case, I have added a server aliases as "pi" to my .ssh/config file using the lines 
"Host pi↵
  Hostname 192.168.178.40↵
  User pi"↵  
I was able to do C-x C-f /pi:~/my-file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Haven't upgraded to 24.1 yet, but prior to that the path would have been:

> C-x C-f /scp:username@192.168.1.23:/path_to_file.rb

Comment: nope does not work, do i need to add something to my .emacs.d directory?